# how to load sql server table(varchar(max) or nvarchar(max)) data into text file using ssis

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

Hi Friends I have one doubt in ssis
how to load  sql server table data into flat file using ssis package
source sql server table like below : in this table have multiple histore table information have.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[testobjects11](
    [ObjectText] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ObjectType] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ObjectName] [nvarchar](max) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
INSERT [dbo].[testobjects11] ([ObjectText], [ObjectType], [ObjectName]) VALUES (N'create table [testobjects] (  [tablesttructure] nvarchar(MAX)  NULL )', N'U ', N'test')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[testobjects11] ([ObjectText], [ObjectType], [ObjectName]) VALUES (N'create table [testobjects1] (  [ObjectText] nvarchar(MAX)  NULL   [ObjectType] nvarchar(MAX)  NULL   [ObjectName] nvarchar(MAX)  NULL )', N'U ', N'test1')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[testobjects11] ([ObjectText], [ObjectType], [ObjectName]) VALUES (N'create table [test123] (  [id] int  NOT NULL   [name] varchar(50)  NOT NULL   [sal] int  NOT NULL )', N'U ', N'test3')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[testobjects11] ([ObjectText], [ObjectType], [ObjectName]) VALUES (N'create table [test] (  [Freight bill origin terminal ID] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Freight bill sequence number] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Destination terminal ID] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Type of shipment] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Total pieces, this shipment] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Total charges this shipment, freight] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Total Pro charges] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Billing terms] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Pickup driver number] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Pickup driver run] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Pickup unit] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Shipper''s B/L #] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Special commodity code] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Palletized freight code] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Trailer number] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Trailer owner SCAT code] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Consignee code] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Consignee name] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Consignee address 1] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Consignee address 2] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Consignee city] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Consignee state] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Consignee zip code] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Consignee zip + 4 code] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Shipper code] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Shipper name] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Shipper address 1] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Shipper address 2] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Shipper city] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Shipper state] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Shipper zip code] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Shipper zip + 4 code] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Transfer from carrier] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Transfer from carrier at] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Transfer from F/B #] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Transfer to carrier] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Transfer to carrier at] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Split charges: From %''age] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Split charges: NP %''age] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Split charges: To %''age] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Split charges: From $] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Split charges: NP $] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Split charges: To $] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Pro split charges: From $] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Pro Split charges: NP $] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Pro Split charges: To $] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Estimated revenue] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [COD amount] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Origin terminal revenue] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Destination terminal revenue] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Accessorial code #1] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Accessorial amount #1] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Accessorial code #2] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Accessorial amount #2] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Accessorial code #3] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Accessorial amount #3] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Accessorial code #4] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Accessorial amount #4] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Accessorial code #5] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Accessorial amount #5] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Accessorial code #6] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Accessorial amount #6] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Allowance amount, dollars] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Allowance percentage] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Double dip amount, dollars] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Double dip percentage] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Print status] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Relay/intermediate terminal ID] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Century of delivery to R/T] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Not used] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Time of delivery to R/T] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Road manifest OT] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Road manifest number] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [City manifest OT] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [City manifest number] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Number of bring-backs] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Last bring-back code] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Delivered to customer code] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Delivery century] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Not used1] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Delivery code] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Delivery suffix] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Cross-reference pro OT] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Cross-reference pro number] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Suffix code] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Pro control status] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Pro day sequence code] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Company code] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Bill-to address] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Bill-to code] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Actual billed-to code] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Total calculated weight] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Total rated weight] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Pro entry century] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Not used2] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Pro entry time, HHMMSS] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Entry person ID] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Century revenue recorded] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Not used3] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Origin terminal revenue taken] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Destination terminal revenue taken] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Origin terminal revenue adjustment] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Destination terminal revenue adjust] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Allowance Basing Code] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Billing century] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Not used4] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Billed amount] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Billing status code] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Accessorial Audit Flag] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Billing type code] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [COD Terms (P/C)] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [COD Fee] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Hold billing code] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Void billing code] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Prepaid/collect billing] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Allowance test code] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Payable status code] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Interline payable carrier code] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Interline payable setup century] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Not used5] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Interline payable amount] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Coding status for prepaids] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Coding status for collects] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Coding status for consignees/prepai] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Extra status code 1] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Extra status code 2] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Extra status code 3] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Extra status code 4] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Total accessorial amount from FA] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Extra amount code 6] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [# OF PIPES] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [# OF DRUMS] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [# OF PALLETS] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [# OF UNPALLETIZED PIECES] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [FB MATCHED CONSIGNEE NUMBER] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [FROM CARTAGE CARRIER CODE] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [FROM CARTAGE CHARGE] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [FROM CARTAGE BILLING CODE] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [TO CARTAGE CARRIER CODE] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [TO CARTAGE CHARGE] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [TO CARTAGE BILLING CODE] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Century of Interline dlvy] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Not used6] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Int. Delv. Carrier Scac] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Int. Carrier Dlv Pro.] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Century of Intlin Appt] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Not used7] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Int. Delivery Status code..] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Int. Delivery Notify Code..] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Bill to name] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Bill to address 1] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Bill to address 2] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Bill to city] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Bill to state] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Bill to zip code] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Bill to zip + 4 code] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Total Cube] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Class Revenue] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Hazardous Flag] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Freezable Flag] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Guaranteed/Time Definite ID] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Hi Value Code] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Shippers P.O. Number] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Shippers Dept Number] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Forced Allowance Percentage] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Rating Aggregate Code] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Rating Aggregate Wgt] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Shp Ldg All Amt$] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Shp Ldg All Pct] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Cns Unldg All Amt$] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Cns Undgl All Pct] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [3rd Pty Comm. Amt$] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [3rd Pty Comm. Pct] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Special Exemption Code] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [PRE-APPT/HOT FLAG] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Auto Rate Base Suf] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Auto Rate Base No.] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Auto Rate Tariff#] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Rated by-Cust Code] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Rated by-Inb/Otb/3rd] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Manual Rate Code] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Custom Rated Code] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Auto Re-Rate Flag] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Int. From-Orig Shipper Code] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Int. To-Finl Consgne Code] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Special Customer Ref] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Pickup driver run1] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Accessorial Status #1] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Accessorial Status #2] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Accessorial Status #3] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Accessorial Status #4] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Accessorial Status #5] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Accessorial Status #6] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [LAST UPDATE USER] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Time Stamp] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Billing date] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Int. Delv Appt Date] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Delivery date] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Interline Dlvy Date] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Interline payable setup date] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Pro entry date] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Date revenue recorded] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Date of delivery to R/T] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Biller SSN#] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [PICKUP NUMBER] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [MANUAL FORCED DISCOUNT%] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [RATE STATUS BYTE#1] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [RATE STATUS BYTE#2] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Adjstd Date of pickup] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [MIN RATED PRO] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Hot/Committed Date] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Time Open] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Time Close] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Distribution Pickup Label # ] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Projected Receive Date] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Distribution SCAC Code] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Linehaul Trailer #] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Actual Pickup Date] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Quote Reference #] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Message ID Term Abrv] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Message Sequence #] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Break Bulk Msg Seq #] nvarchar(250)  NULL   [Column223] nvarchar(250)  NULL )', N'U ', N'test4')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[testobjects11] ([ObjectText], [ObjectType], [ObjectName]) VALUES (N'create table [abctest123] (  [lat] varchar(500)  NULL   [long] varchar(500)  NULL   [add] varchar(500)  NULL   [city] varchar(500)  NULL   [state] varchar(5000)  NULL )', N'U ', N'test5')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[testobjects11] ([ObjectText], [ObjectType], [ObjectName]) VALUES (N'create table [final] (  [id] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL   [lat] varchar(500)  NULL   [long] varchar(500)  NULL   [add] varchar(500)  NULL   [city] varchar(500)  NULL   [state] varchar(5000)  NULL )', N'U ', N'test6')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[testobjects11] ([ObjectText], [ObjectType], [ObjectName]) VALUES (N'create table [emp] (  [id] int  NULL   [salesmoney] money  NULL   [salesdecimal] decimal(10, 2)  NULL   [salesnum] numeric  NULL )', N'U ', N'test7')
GO
```

I want load this testobjects11 table data into object.txt file(destination)

I have tried like below steps:
step1 : drag and drop oledb source and connfigure to soruce table(testobjects11)
after that I have used derived column task and write expression like (DT_NTEXT)ObjectText
after that 
I drag and drop the flatfile destination task and configure to the file
after that I execute the ssis package ,but package is faieled .
I got error like below:

```
[Flat File Destination [12]] Error: The data type for "Flat File Destination.Inputs[Flat File Destination Input].Columns[ObjectText]" is DT_NTEXT, which is not supported with ANSI files. Use DT_TEXT instead and convert the data to DT_NTEXT using the data conversion component.
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: "Flat File Destination" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".
```

can you please tell me how to achive this task in ssis

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're going to need to alter your Derived Column transformation, e.g.:

```
(DT_TEXT, 1252) ObjectText
```

If you are confident the constraint would be met, you could also cast these values in your OLE DB Source, e.g.:

```
CAST(ObjectText AS nvarchar(4000)) ObjectText
```

This would then pass through your Data Flow as DT_WSTR with a length of 4,000 as opposed to DT_NTEXT.

Comment: I replicated and used DT_Text, which works like charm.